# how to compare a variable with blank value in selenium?

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to check whether the variable is storing blank value or not.
I tried out comparing it with '' or "" or NULL or null, but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out below solution

```
storeValue  |  element  |  test
store       |           |  j  (blank value)
gotoIf      |  storedVars['test']==storedVars['j']  |  true
getEval     |  alert("test Variable Value is not blank")
gotolabel   |  finish
label       |  true
getEval     |  alert("test Variable Value is blank")
label       |  finish
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `verifyEval` command for this. Try following script,

> verifyEval |   this.page().findElement("id=gbqfq").value == '' | true